# Angular 4 *ngIf/else does not work with md-spinner

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ng-if

Here's my code:

```
<div *ngIf="queryState == 'RUNNING'; else spt" fxLayout="row">
  <md-spinner></md-spinner>
</div>
<ng-template #spt>
  <div fxLayout="row" fxFill>
    No data to show!
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Now when `queryState` is equal to `'RUNNING'`, `*ngIf` correctly shows the `md-spinner`, but when `queryState` is not equal to `'RUNNING'`, the `md-spinner` does not go away; it just stays there and keeps on rotating and does not show `No data to show!` from `ng-template`.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to output the value of `{{ queryState == 'RUNNING' }}` to see if it's actually changing? Have you tried to apply that same logic to other elements?

Comment: @crash: Yes, `queryState` changes its value from `'RUNNING'` to `'FINISHED'`, but `*ngIf` does not remove `md-spinner`.

Comment: @Vikrant [**I can't reproduce it here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/mGCoSicLHk9YBB0hZPWC).

Comment: Where and how do you update `queryState`?

Comment: Through a  `service`. I have also verified that the `queryState` changes its value. But now have given up and moved on to other critical parts of my app!!!